# Person and group multible selections separate names

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting, person-or-group

So I got this problem where the names stands after eachother, is there anyway to move Alexanders name under Jonas?

See picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [JSON Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to set a custom format.  See [the example on formatting users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#complex-html-elements-formatting), is probably pretty close to what you want to do, though it also includes thumbnail of the user's profile photo.

Comment: It kinda worked but I still want it to be clickable and all information about the person pops up. Is there a code where you just can move it down?

Comment: No, but you can add hyperlink in the json to link to the user's profile page.